# DIV/CSS Layout Instead of Tables

Tags: css, html

I am having a hard time getting my layout setup using divs. I got most of the page setup, but I had to use tables in one area and I was wondering if there is a way to replace these tables with div boxes.

I couldn't figure out how to attach the html source here, so I am attaching a link to the page in question..

http://www.guitarlessonsbydrew.com/killeens/index2.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you against tables ?

Comment: I tried putting divs within a container where the tables are but then the footer gets screwed up. I am trying to use the container to give a black border. I was trying to divs side by side and a footer div underneath and the footer wouldn't cooperate. I put float left on the side by side div boxes.

Comment: I'm not necessarily against using tables, but most modern sites are using div and css and I am trying to teach myself to do it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing the below

1)Remove the table
2)Replace your `table columns` with `div` and `float` the `divs`
3)`clear` the `floats` after the `end` of the `div`, so it does not screw your footer.

HTML :

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="column-1">
        <p><b>Welcome!</b></p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
        <p><img src="location.png" alt="location"></p>
        <p><iframe src="">....</iframe> </p>
    </div>  
  <div class="clr"></div>      
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
<div class="footer"> Copyright  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.column-1{
     float:left;
     width:60%; }
.column-2{
     float:right;
     width:40%;}
.clr{
     clear:both;
    }
```

You can refer the below link for clearing floats
[Clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Comment: I think something might ben missing. I have revised the code and it got a little out of whack. Original (http://guitarlessonsbydrew.com/killeens/index2.html) Revised (http://guitarlessonsbydrew.com/killeens/index3.html)

Comment: @user2999299: it would be better if you could provide a fiddle or code, to know what problem ur facing exactly. cause the above code worked fine for me.

Comment: @user2999299: i have updated the code again. you should clear the floats inside the content div as well. Please refer the link which i have given, that explains clearly, what was the issue. Let me know if it works fine now

Comment: I was missing a closing div. The index3 page works perfectly. Thanks!! BTW, for the future reference, how do I insert code? I tried the pre tags and it doesn't put the code in.

Comment: @user2999299:Please do accept the answer, if you are satisfied. insert code as in to display the code itself in the html page?.Try <xmp>
   ...code...
</xmp>